# how can solve phpmyadmin 403 on laragon?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laragon

I installed laragon.exe.After start all services, the apache and mysql run without any problem.But when I write localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me below messages:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin on this server.

please help on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: A simple [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=laragon+403+forbidden&oq=lar&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j0l2j69i60j0.946j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) search yielded [this](https://forum.laragon.org/topic/98/how-to-update-phpmyadmin) page.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The latest Laragon has not included the phpMyAdmin by default, so you will not be able to access **localhost/phpmyadmin**.

If you want to use phpMyAdmin in Laragon, please follow the below steps:

1. Download the latest phpMyAdmin zip from [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads)
2. Extract to the ***path/to/laragon/etc/apps***
3. The folder name must be **phpMyAdmin**
4. Restart Laragon and enjoy

Comment: saved me a day :)

Comment: If you need to give access from outside, don't forget to replace the lines "Require local" by Require all granted into the file alias\phpmyadmin.conf

Comment: Stills works like charm...